# How to query difference duplicate data

Tags: sql, ms-access

## SQL

I have data around

```
BOMcat | BOM  | AltBOM | Counter |   ChangeNo   | DeID | DID | PreCounter | Baseqty
M      | 7882 | A      |      26 | GUC320140101 |  X   |     |            |100.000
M      | 7882 | B      |       1 | GUC320140101 |  X   |     |            |100.500
M      | 7882 | B      |     307 | GUC320141225 |  X   |     |  1         |100.500
M      | 9772 | 01     |     600 | GUC120140904 |  X   |     |  397       |116.188
M      | 9772 | 01     |     601 | GUC120150504 |  X   |     |  600       |116.488
M      | 9772 | 01     |    1021 | GUC120150703 |  X   |     | 601        |116.488
```

i want to select `1 BOM/1 AltBOM` by condition is select last `ChangeNo`.

- `PreCounter`: Mean this line has change what line EX. PreCounter 1 this line has change `BOM` has `Counter 1`
- 'Changeno': Structrue is GUCXYYYYMMDD 
            - X: running number 
            - YYYY: Year 
            - MM: Month 
            - DD: Date

## Expect Result

```
M   |   7882 |  A    |     26  | GUC320140101 | X |  |      | 100.000
M   |   7882 |  B    |    307  | GUC320141225 | X |  |  1   | 100.500
M   |   9772 |  01   |   1021  | GUC120150703 | X |  |  601 | 116.488
```

Comment: What query did you try to get the data yourself?

Comment: I want to query data in MS access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MS Access I would do this with a correlated subquery in the `where` clause:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.changeno = (select max(t2.changeno)
                    from t t2
                    where t2.bom = t.bom and t2.altbom = t.altbom
                   );
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to use `NOT EXISTS` to return a row if there are no other row with same BOM/AltBOM that has a higher ChangeNo:

```
select *
from tablename t1
where not exists (select * from tablename t2
                  where t2.BOM = t1.BOM
                    and t2.AltBOM = t1.AltBOM
                    and t2.ChangeNo > t1.ChangeNo)
```

Alternatively, do a self `join` with a `group by`:

```
select t1.*
from tablename t1
    join (select BOM, AltBOM, MAX(ChangeNo) as ChangeNo
          from tablename
          group by BOM, AltBOM) t2
    on t1.BOM = t2.BOM and t1.AltBOM = t2.AltBOM and t1.ChangeNo = t2.ChangeNo
```

Comment: Thank you so much, i will use this logic if performance as more my code